# Jquery - If conditional

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following conditional jquery function:
Is there a way of having an "or" in a conditional?
Ideally I want a single function, where if the values are **1,2 or 3** hide the corresponding elements. Is this possible?  My goal is just to have more efficient, cleaner code, this seems unnecessarily long and reptitive.

```
$("#Catalogue").change(function () {
            var a = $(this).val();
            console.log(a);
            if (a == 1) {
                $("#DeliveryMethod").hide();
                $("#CatalogueID").hide();
            }
            else if (a == 2) {
                $("#DeliveryMethod").hide();
                $("#CatalogueID").hide();
            }
            else if (a == 3) {
                $("#CatalogueID").show();
                $("#DeliveryMethod").hide();
            }
            else {
                $("#DeliveryMethod").show();
                $("#CatalogueID").hide();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Use `if(a == 1 || a == 2 || a == 3){ ... }`

Comment: Or `if(a >= 1 && a <= 3){ ... }`

Comment: Post one of these as an answer Il award it to you

Comment: there's an inversion in show and hide and correponding element between the last `elseif` and `else` clause. Typo or wanted ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
if(a == 1 || a == 2 || a == 3){ ... }
```

OR

```
if(a >= 1 && a <= 3){ ... }
```